# Reset a react-query useQuery hook to clear data on the rendered page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

I am writing a search component which uses react query to fetch the data.

```
export default function useSearchResults({
    query,
}: IUseGetSearchResultsProps): QueryObserverResult<IResponse<ISearchResult>> {
    return useQuery(
        [SEARCH_RESULT_QUERY_KEY, { query }],
        (): Promise<IResponse<ISearchResult>> => getSearchResults({ query }),
        {
            enabled: false,
            keepPreviousData: true,
        }
    );
}
```

Which I then import in my component, and refetch the data when the user enters a search term:

```
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState<string>("");
  const handleOnChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const { data, refetch } = useSearchResults({ query: searchTerm });

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm.length > 0) {
      refetch();
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);
```

There  is a requirement to not show any data when there is nothing in the `searchTerm` i.e. `searchTerm` is an empty string.

However, the API returns all results when a search term is not passed to it and I cannot alter that behaviour.

Is there a way to reset `useQuery` hook to return `data` as an empty array?

Comment: What if the user never entered in a search term? Would it show no results or all the results? Are you only showing no results if the user has already searched and the search term is empty?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me please point out that disabling a query and using `refetch` in an effect is not per-se idiomatic react-query.

Since react-query will automatically refetch whenever the query key changes, and you also already have local state that you put into the query key, you can drive the `enabled` flag with that information and get rid of the effect:

```
export default function useSearchResults({
    query,
}: IUseGetSearchResultsProps): QueryObserverResult<IResponse<ISearchResult>> {
    return useQuery(
        [SEARCH_RESULT_QUERY_KEY, { query }],
        (): Promise<IResponse<ISearchResult>> => getSearchResults({ query }),
        {
            enabled: Boolean(query),
            keepPreviousData: true,
        }
    );
}
```

```
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const handleOnChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  const { data, refetch } = useSearchResults({ query: searchTerm });
```

The query will start `disabled` and will `enable` itself, with all the react-query advantages like background updates as soon as the user has typed in a query, and it will also refetch when the input changes.

Since the query will be disabled for an empty string, the backend api should never be hit with that, so your data will stay `undefined`, which you can then coerce to empty array.

Comment: It's a requirement that we need to refetch with the existing query each time users clicks a button. Unfortunately with the above approach, this will not be possible since query will always stay the same. Is there a quick solution for this issue?

Comment: if the variables the query depends on are the same, you can just call refetch(). Thats what it's for.

Comment: Makes sense. However each time the button is clicked we would need to check if the input data changed, if not then `refetch` if yes, then do nothing as the query hook will fetch with the new input. Was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: yep, that's right. I've been there, too :)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is modify the response in the useQuery hook before returning it from `useSearchResults`.

```
function useSearchResults({ query }) {
  return useQuery(["search", { query }], () => {
    if (!query) return [];
    return getSearchResults({ query });
  });
}
```

Notice how it doesn't immediately return `getSearchResults`? The query function is a good place to perform transforms and such as they're needed.

I'm not completely sure of the UX but it sounds like you want to show results, then filter results based on a search term, and then if the search box has an empty string, display no results? If you can clear this up I can modify the example below.

Here's a sandbox to demonstrate this: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-wilbur-xbcfy

Comment: Yes that is what I was looking for!