# I'm using react query to fetch new movie info

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I was building a movies web app using react and tmdb api. I have a page called `Movies.jsx` where all movies are fetched using react query and that works fine. I also have `movieInfo.jsx` page that responsible for showing details of a specific movie based on id in url using also react query.
The problem here is when I open a movie and go back to the movies list and then open another one, the `movieInfo` page shows the previous movie data. After some seconds it's re rendering the UI and shows the one I clicked on.
How do I solve this issue so the previous movie info will not show after clicking a different movie?

I'm new to react query, Thanks

Trying to fetch data using react query

Code of movieInfo.jsx :

```
const { movieId } = useParams();
const { data: movieInfo, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["movieInfo"],
    queryFn: () => getMovieInfoById(movieId),
    onError: (err) => console.log(err),
  });
```

Comment: Can you provide some minimal example code? It might be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68491200/reset-a-react-query-usequery-hook-to-clear-data-on-the-rendered-page?

Comment: I think refetch the data that may work for you, Before navigating back to the Movies page, you can invalidate the query data for the MovieInfo page. This will force React Query to refetch the data the next time the MovieInfo page is rendered.

Comment: @shahabasparamban can you show me how please

Comment: @ahmedahmedx: Let's try to use `invalidateQuery(movieInfo)` each time you go back to movie list page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason for your issue is default caching mechanism of `react-query`.

You defined a query key for movie info api call `movieInfo` and `react-query` thinks it is the same request and use cached response instead of refetching the new one.

You should define queryKey line in this guide from tanstack

```
// An individual movie
useQuery({ queryKey: ['movieInfo', 5], ... })
```

The full document here: https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/guides/query-keys#array-keys-with-variables

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue while using React Query. The problem seems to be that the `queryKey` used by `React Query` isn't being updated for each movie, which causes it to initially load data from the cache (hence showing the previous movie's info). To fix this, make sure to include the `movieId` in your `queryKey`.

This way, `React Query` knows to fetch new data for each movie.

Here's a quick fix:

```
const { movieId } = useParams();
const { data: movieInfo, isLoading } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["movieInfo", movieId], // Updated queryKey
  queryFn: () => getMovieInfoById(movieId),
  onError: (err) => console.log(err),
});
```

Adding `movieId` to the `queryKey` makes each query unique to its movie, ensuring the correct movie data is fetched when you switch between movies.

Hope this helps!